# How does a dielectric form in an electrolytic capacitor?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, capacitance, dielectric

I have found that this happens through anodic oxidation, but can't seem to find how this happens. Why do some metals form an insulating layer when in contact with an electrolyte?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The insulating layer in an aluminum foil-based electrolytic capacitor forms when electrical current is forced to flow through an alkaline solution or paste that is in contact with the aluminum. If the polarity if the current flow is correct, a film of aluminum oxide forms on the surface of the aluminum, which serves as the dielectric. This process is called *anodization* and you can search on this term to learn the exact electrochemical reactions at work here.

What sets aluminum apart from most other common metals is that the anodized oxide film thus formed is extremely uniform in thickness, clings very tightly to the aluminum underneath it, has very high resistance to dielectric breakdown, and is very durable. Furthermore it exhibits all these properties even when the thickness of the anodized film is only of order ~ one thousandth of an inch.

The thinness of the anodized film means that the capacity in farads of a capacitor in which that film is the dielectric, the paste is one capacitor plate, and the aluminum film is the other can be made very large.

The disadvantages of the *electrolytic capacitor* are that the paste dries up with time and the electrochemistry stops, and if unused for a long period of time, the anodized film slowly breaks down- and if wired up backwards to the power supply, the electrochemistry runs backwards, the anodized dielectric dissolves, and the capacitor is instantly turned into an explosive device.

Comment: Thank you! Watched some videos about anodization and now it's clear.